Are there no special rules for betas?
A beta that just started will hardly end up with a lot of high rep users in a short time frame. Are there any special rules w.r.t. the reputation needed for certain actions or is it the same as on any other SE network site for betas, too?
Examples:

adding new tags
editing without the edit ending up in the queue
being able to peer review edits in the first place

If I see this correctly from the list of what the rep levels provide, it looks like none of us can even peer review edits, right? Who is doing it then? Is that the SE staff?

As I write, two users can review suggested edits (it comes with the edit privilege at 1000 rep), but they won't see a notification (that comes with the moderator tools privilege at 2000 rep), and only one can review tag wiki suggestions (1500 rep). Don't worry, this number will quickly grow.
I see that you're mostly active on graduated sites; the privilege levels are a lot lower on beta sites (e.g. 500 instead of 3000 for closing, 150 instead of 300 (and more on SO) for creating tags). You can browse the privilege levels on this site, and see your progress towards them, at /privileges.
In a couple of weeks, moderators will be appointed. Moderators have all user privileges regardless of reputation (and a few more besides).
Until then, Stack Exchange staff perform support tasks such as reviewing edits that the community can't handle yet.

@Gilles: thanks for taking the time to answer. Much appreciated. The /privileges URI is particularly useful. Where do you find such meta-information? Is there something like an overview of such resources?

@0xC0000022L /privileges is linked from the [faq]. I've been participating in SE for over two years, including 3 private betas, so I'm beginning to know where to find things. There's a lot of information on the main meta, but it is hard to search for.

@Gilles: thanks for sharing!

Just adding to what Gilles mentioned, the rep limits for the various privileges vary depending on what phase the site is in. Here is the complete list :
Main sites

Action                                          Priv ß Public ß  Golden       SO
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Skip lecture on how to ask                        None     None    None       10
Answer questions on the site's meta                  5        5       5      N/A
Add images, 2+ link, answer protected questions      1       10?     10       10
Create community-wiki answers                       10       10      10       10
Vote up                                              1       15      15       15
Flag offensive                                      15       15      15       15
Chat                                               20 global reputation*      20
Leave comments on any questions or answer            1       50      50       50
Make bounties                                       75       75      75       75
Create a chat room                                100 global reputation*     100
Vote down (costs 1 rep)                              1      100     100      100
Edit community wiki posts                            1      100     100      100
Create new tags                                      1      150     300     1500
Vote in moderator elections                        No elections     150      150
+100 rep to all linked accounts                    200      200     200      200
Reduced advertisements                        No advertisements     200      200
Retag questions                                      1      200     500      500
Vote to close, reopen, or migrate your questions     1      250     250      250
Nominate for moderator                             No elections     300      300?
Show up/down vote splits; user card                100      750    1000     1000
Create a gallery chat room                       1000 global reputation*    1000
Edit other people's posts                          500     1000    2000     2000
Suggest tag synonyms                              1250     1250    2500     2500
Vote to close, reopen, or migrate any questions      1      500    3000     3000
Approve tag wiki edits                             750     1500    5000     5000
Delete closed questions, moderation tools         1000     2000   10000    10000
Reduce captchas                                   1000?    2000   10000    10000
Review chat flags                               10000 global reputation*   10000
Protect questions                                 1750     3500   15000    15000
Edit tag wikis immediately; more deletion         2000     4000   20000    20000
Painting of unicorns, signed by Jeff and Joel                    200000   200000

Source.

The full, current list for this site is always at /privileges.

@AshRj: thanks for taking the time to answer. Much appreciated.
